# select on results of a select

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a database table that records movements of users in a game. Each time they move I record their user id, the move_index (increments each row) and the id of the zone they are in. I have a special move_index value of -1 to indicate the last movement of that user.

```
id   user_id  move_index  zone_id   
----------------------------------------------------------------
0    11        0          0  
1    11        1          0 
2    11        2          0   
3    11       -1          3    

4    22        0          0   
5    22        1          1   
6    22        2          1    
7    22       -1          3
```

I want to do two things with sql:

- Detect all the users who started and finished in specific zones (e.g. started in zone 0 and finished in zone 3)
- Extending the above, detect all users who started and finished in specific zones AND passed through a specific zone.

I know how to do this with multiple SQL statements & java - but I don't know how to do this in a single SQL statement. Do I need to do a select and then a select on the results of this select ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply carry out a [SUBQUERY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) to achieve this within a "single" query.

e.g.: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);`

In essence, you're using the results of the "inner" SELECT as the working data set for the "outer" SELECT.

Comment: Thanks - I figured it from here. Is this standard SQL (i.e. would it work on Oracle too ?). And, performance issues aside, is there any limit on the number of SUBQUERIES you can do ?

Comment: @Kevin Subqueries are in pretty much every RDBMS (not sure what standard they're a part of that said.) In terms of limits, it really depends on the size/shape of your data, but I'm generally try not to use more than a single subquery if at all possible. (In many case a plain [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), or sometimes a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) or a temporary table may be more appropriate.)

Comment: Very clear and useful answer. Thanks for saving me lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct user_id from table where (move_index=0 and zone_id=0) and (move_index=-1 and zone_id=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

here goes your query:

```
SELECT *, (foo = true AND bar = true) as foobar
FROM foo
WHERE (id = 3)
```

You can use the foobar value in your query result to determine the outcome of the second equation.

I think, this should give you a hint on how to do it.